# Error when concatenating two groupby Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has daily sales data using which I created a groupby function as below:

```
df_new1 = df_1.groupby(['emp_id']).size() 
df_new2 = df_2.groupby(['emp_id']).size()
```

Sample output of df_new1:

```
emp_id,count1
101,2
102,4
```

Sample output of df_new2:

```
emp_id,count2
101,4
102,6
```

I am trying to compare the above two Dataframes (`df_new1` and `df_new2`) as below:

```
new_df = pd.concat(df_new1, df_new2)
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"
```

Expected output:

```
emp_id,count1,count2
101,2,4
102,4,6
```

where count1 is value from `df_new1` and count2 is value from `df_new2`

Comment: `pd.concat([df_new1, df_new2])` you should pass a list of dataframes in concat

Comment: @anky_91, sorry if I mis-communicated. I am trying to compare values from df_new1 with df_new2. Using pd.concat seems to add all rows of the 2 Dataframes one below the other..

Comment: how do you want to compare? can you add a little data and expected output please. ? Thanks. :)

Comment: @anky_91 have updated initial post with some sample data, thanks

Comment: `df_new1.merge(df_new2, on='emp_id')`

Comment: @anky_91 will review the link. However this throws an error "ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186694/discussion-between-anky-91-and-scott-martin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both df_new1 and df_new2 are Series not data frames as you did not reset index after groupby. You can concat multiple series, they will get concatenated on the index. Try

```
new_df = pd.concat([df_new1, df_new2], axis = 1)
```